# how to convert decimal to ieee754

Tags: python, ieee-754

I am trying to convert decimal to ieee754 using the following:

```py
import struct
f = 20.0

c=struct.pack('f', f).encode('hex')
print(c)
```

but I get the result:

```py
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) on Windows (64 bits).
This is the Pyzo interpreter with integrated event loop for PYQT5.
Type 'help' for help, type '?' for a list of *magic* commands.
Running script: "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    c=struct.pack('f', f).encode('hex')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was expecting a result in the form `2af0` etc